# Sonarqube - Resolution changed to FIXED

Tags: sonarqube

I have a strange behaviour while analysing my Java Code.
The analysis is done on a daily basis.
On the first run some issue are identified, so far so good.

After the next run there are issues marked as Fixed.


The Message i got in sonarQube:

> 20. Juli 2015 10:33 Uhr         Created
> 21. Juli 2015 20:30 Uhr         Resolution changed to FIXED
>       Status changed to CLOSED (was OPEN)

But there was no change at this File between the two runs.....

**Java: JDK 1.8.0_u45

SonarQube: 5.1.1**

Any Idea???
Thanks in advance
Kai

Comment: it is reproducible or did you have this behavior just once?

Comment: what was the issue title ?